# C# WebService endpoint problem

Tags: c#, endpoint

I'm creating a webservice client. And I have the problem - in MainWindow.xaml there is a message: 'Could not find endpoint element with name 'LightsWSSoap' and contract  'LightsWS.LightsWSSoap'  in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this name could be found in the client element.'
In this file I have something like:

```
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:LightsClient2.ViewModels"
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MainWindowViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
```

And in the MainWindowViewModel the constructor of webservice is used:

```
LightsWSSoap lService = new LightsWSSoapClient("LightsWSSoap");
```

Where 'LightsWS' is the name of the Service.

There is an app.config file and there are enpoints definitions in it:

```
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://xxx/Lights/LightsWS.asmx"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="LightsWSSoap"
            contract="LightsWS.LightsWSSoap" name="LightsWSSoap" />
        <endpoint address="http://xxx/Lights/LightsWS.asmx"
            binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="LightsWSSoap12"
            contract="LightsWS.LightsWSSoap" name="LightsWSSoap12" />
    </client>
```

What is wrong? Any ideas?

Comment: Is `LightsWS.LightsWSSoap` - interface? (It should be) If it is, so why don't it starts with I (`LightsWS.ILightsWSSoap`). Which type of endpoint you intend to use? basicHttpBinding or customBinding?

Comment: This is an interface and it was automatically generated by VS; at the moment it's basic

Comment: Have you solved your problem yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to configure your client endpoint in the App.Config file in your WPF application.

If there is not already an App.Config file you can create one by adding a new item to your project and selecting "Application Configuration File".

The contents of App.Config should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="LightsWS.LightsWSSoap" name="LightsWSSoap"  />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

There is a lot more detailed information on MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731745%28VS.90%29.aspx.

Answer (score 2):

You should add app.config file with definition of your endpoint. Usually it is create by Visual Studio. But if you created your ServiceReference in another assembly (for example, is separate dll), then just copy app.config from that assembly to your WpfApplication.

Answer (score 0):

Try the ideas in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328840/3305260#3305260), especially the namespaces.