# Zero application endpoint error when I try to start a service

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, windows-services

I think I've literally checked for all possibilities but I still keep getting this error (written in eventvwr) when I attempt to start my service:

> Service cannot be started. System.InvalidOperationException: Service
>   'NexolNotifierWinService.NexolNotifier'  has zero application
>   (non-infrastructure) endpoints. This might be because no configuration
>   file was found for your application, or because no service element
>   matching the service name could be found in the configuration file, or
>   because no endpoints were defined in the service element.

Service installation goes smoothly using installutil.

I'm genuinely not sure why I'm having this error. It's just a simple Windows Service project, so there's no app.config to mess around with either.

Here's my code:

Program.cs

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
        { 
            new NexolNotifierService() 
        };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
    }
}
```

NexolNotifierService.cs

```
public partial class NexolNotifierService : ServiceBase
{
    private ServiceHost host;
    public NexolNotifierService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.ServiceName = "NexolNotifierService";
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        Type serviceType = typeof(NexolNotifier);
        host = new ServiceHost(serviceType);
        host.Open();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        if (host != null)
            host.Close();
    }
}
```

ProjectInstaller.Designer.cs (For installing service)

```
private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.serviceProcessInstaller1 = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller();
        this.serviceInstaller1 = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller();
        // 
        // serviceProcessInstaller1
        // 
        this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Account = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.LocalSystem; 
        this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Password = null;
        this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Username = null;
        // 
        // serviceInstaller1
        // 
        this.serviceInstaller1.ServiceName = "NexolNotifierService";
        this.serviceInstaller1.StartType = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceStartMode.Automatic;
        // 
        // ProjectInstaller
        // 
        this.Installers.AddRange(new System.Configuration.Install.Installer[] {
        this.serviceProcessInstaller1,
        this.serviceInstaller1});

    }
```

and my actual service:

NexolNotifier.cs

```
public class NexolNotifier
{
    public NexolNotifier()
    {
        ....
    }
```

Service was added from add new project->Windows Service in Visual Studio 2008.

I'm just trying to get a very simple windows service working. From what I can see, there is zero reason why this shouldn't work.

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328840/service-has-zero-application-non-infrastructure-endpoints , you need config file

Comment: @wudzik My question is, why? It's not a WCF project, it's a local windows service that was generated by the Windows Service wizard, which didn't provided me with a config file.

Comment: Are you running the service in Administrator mode? It can't create the end point otherwise. Check your event log...

Comment: @Aron Yes, I'm running the service in admin mode.

Comment: @marc_s So, let me get this straight. My intention is to create a local windows service that will not do any networking, yet I'm forced to use WCF to do that? So then I have to add app.config with an empty http binding settings? Seriously? Is this how MSFT really designed this or am I being naive in my assumption?

Comment: Well, what are you using a `ServiceHost` for, if you don't want to do any *networking* or communication? The ServiceHost is **for hosting WCF services** .....

Comment: @marc_s That is what the numerous tutorials (MSDN,code project etc) used. In fact, I couldn't find a single example on google that doesn't use ServiceHost for hosting local Windows Services. Does this mean I'm out of options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***What do you want to do?***

If you want just a **plain** Windows Service - no communication, nothing - then **you don't need `ServiceHost`!** You just need to derive from the `ServiceBase` class in the .NET framework and implement/override some of the methods - that's all. Read values from a database, do something with them, send e-mails - whatever - you will **never** need a `ServiceHost` for this!

If you use `ServiceHost` then you're using the **WCF infrastructure**, which means, you're writing a self-hosted web service.

So **what do you want to do, really??**

What's the task/job that your Windows Service is supposed to do?? `ServiceHost` has **nothing** to do with a plain **Windows Service!** `ServiceHost` == WCF - always. You don't **need** a `ServiceHost` for just a plain Windows service

For **just plain Windows service** (no WCF), see e.g.

- [Creating a Basic Windows Service](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14353/Creating-a-Basic-Windows-Service-in-C)
- [Simple Windows Service Sample](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3990/Simple-Windows-Service-Sample)

and **many, many** more samples. Both samples show just a plain Windows service, **no WCF, no `ServiceHost`** anywhere in sight.

Comment: Yes, this is the exact answer I wanted. For some reason, googling C# Windows Service Tutorial only showed results (including MSDN's) that involved ServiceHost. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Add service endpoint from code like this

```
       Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8095/Service");
        serviceHost = new ServiceHost( typeof(YourService), baseAddress );
        serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint( typeof(IYourService), new BasicHttpBinding(), baseAddress );
        serviceHost.Open();
```

Comment: Again, same error. MSDN tutorials did not mention anything about adding an endpoint for a local windows service that will not do any networking. I'm curious as to why adding an endpoint would solve the matter.

Comment: I supose some endpoint is needed, but not sure how to make it. Maybe you should try using http://topshelf-project.com/ as windows service host? It's simple in use :)